# Weird output while using sed to rename files

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, scripts, sed

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.2` with `GNU sed version 4.7`. I have a bunch of music files that got named weirdly because they did not have all the info I specified to be in the file name. For example, "Bruno Mars - NA - Bruno Mars - The Lazy Song.aiff" Basically, the NA is put in place of the year because that is unknown. What I want to do is rename all of these files to omit the "- NA -" and everything before that, so the file comes out to be "Bruno Mars - The Lazy Song.aiff"

Here is my problem and what I have tried so far:
I coppied a few of the affected files to a different folder and used the command `sed 's/^.*NA -//' *` to try and fix the naming, but I started to get very weird output from the terminal, see [this](https://pastebin.com/AZSyCf17). I have tried reinstalling sed, using `rename sed 's/^.*NA -//' *` and `perl -pi -e 's/^.*NA -//' *` and none of them have worked; however, the rename and perl commands have not produced the same, weird output as before. My gut is telling me that my regex is incorrect, but the documentation says that this should work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `sed 's/^.*NA -//' *` would not *rename* files, it would attempt to replace the pattern in the files' *contents*, streaming the result to the terminal (with potentially weird results, especially if the expansion of `*` includes any binary files).

Comment: You want to use the `rename` command, not sed: see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/prename.1p.html

Comment: @glennjackman That sounds like an answer.

Comment: You have a pastebin error: `Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it.`

Comment: perfect job for [mmv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217683/rename-multiple-files-at-the-same-time)... `mmv '* - NA - *.aiff' '#2.aiff'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `sed 's/^.*NA -//' *` would not rename files, it would attempt to replace the pattern in the files' contents, streaming the result to the terminal (with potentially weird results, especially if the expansion of `*` includes any binary files).

The command `perl -pi -e 's/^.*NA -//' *` would do the same, except modifying the contents in place, possibly corrupting your files.

To use sed (or perl itself) for file renaming, you'd need to do something like

```
for f in *; do mv -n -- "$f" "$(sed 's/pattern/replacement' <<<"$f")"
```

or

```
for f in *; do mv -n -- "$f" "$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | sed 's/pattern/replacement')"
```

i.e. passing the name of each file to sed via standard input. However your pattern could just as easily be written as a shell substitution, eliminating the need for sed altogether:

```
for f in *; do mv -n -- "$f" "${f##* - NA - }"; done
```

(I'm assuming you want to remove the leading space as well). The `##*` matches the longest leading character sequence, equivalent to basic regular expression `^.*`

To use perl under the hood, but modifying file *names* rather than contents, you'd want the `rename` command, from package `rename`. (There are other `rename` commands, such as the one from package `util-linux` that work differently.) For example:

```
rename -n 's/^.*? - NA - //' *.aiff
```

(I limited the scope to `.aiff` files, and made the `.*` match non-greedy - a feature that `sed` does not provide - so that it only matches up to the first `- NA -` in case there are multiple instances.) Remove the `-n` once you are satisfied with the proposed re-namings.