# How to change/remove the file extensions of a group of files

Tags: 20.04, sed, find

I have a **bunch of .txt files** in a directory, and I want to be able to **find these files and strip the extension** from the file name.

I can **find the files** using:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt"
./0test.txt
./1test.txt
./2test.txt
./3test.txt
./4test.txt
./5test.txt
./6test.txt
./7test.txt
./8test.txt
./9test.txt
```

I then tried to use **sed command to remove the ".txt" extension**, like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | sed "s/\.txt$//"
```

**But** I just get the **file names listed without their extensions**, and the **actual file names remain unchanged**.

So **how** do you actually **change the file names themselves**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this in bash

```
for v in *.txt ; do mv "$v"  "$(basename "$v" .txt)"; done
```

Comment: Thanks. That works pretty good. Nice and simple too! I just need to understand what it's actually doing. Do you have any ref/links to help me learn? I guess my goal of no loops and using sed isn't viable.

Comment: man basename, its to strip directory and suffix from filenames,  dirname is another useful command- man dirname :). $v is the v variable from the for loop.

Comment: You can get rid of double quotes and simply use `for v in *.txt ; do mv $v  $(basename $v  .txt); done`. To do the reverse use `for v in * ; do mv $v  $v.txt; done`

Answer (score 2):

`$` in a regular expression matches the end of a string, you can't match characters *after* that, only before.

Also `.` needs to be escaped to stop it from having its special meaning (any character).

So:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | sed "s/\.txt$//"
```

---

If you're trying to *rename* the files, then you can use the same regular expression substitution with the perl-based `rename` command

```
rename "s/\.txt$//" *.txt
```

(you don't need `find` when all the files are in a single directory level), or a simple shell loop with `mv`:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv -n -- "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done
```

Comment: well I'm clearly having a dumb day, thanks for being gentle! So the output shows the files without extensions but the actual files remain untouched. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Broadsworde what do you mean by "touched"? are you trying to modify the files' contents, or to rename them? If the latter, then `sed` is not the best tool for the job - you'd want `rename` (or `mmv`, or a shell loop using `mv`, or ...)

Comment: I'm trying to remove the extensions from the actual files. Is sed not capable of modifying file names, perhaps in conjunction with mv. Would prefer to not use rename and keep this a base install capable operation, and if it's possible to do without loops that would be ideal. Trying to keep it super simple.

Comment: @Broadsworde you *can* use `sed`, but you'd need a loop (or something equivalent such as `xargs`) with `mv` . Rather than repeat myself here, please see this related answer [Weird output while using sed to rename files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1336136/178692)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, maybe someone will benefit from this. Last night I needed to do this exact thing with sed, I asked God to show me, I had been trying this :
`echo filename.txt |  sed 's/\.*$//` 
and it just didn't work, it presented the filename including extension as is. This is what God revealed  `echo filename.txt | sed 's/\...*$//'     filename`

This removes not only 3 letter extensions but multiple extensions ie. tar.bz2, tar.xz and even tar.gz also.

```
echo filename.txt | sed 's/\...*$//'     filename
echo filename.epub | sed 's/\...*$//'     filename
echo filename.tar.xz | sed 's/\...*$//'     filename
echo filename.tar.bz2 | sed 's/\...*$//'     filename
echo filename.txt.gz| sed 's/\...*$//'     filename
```

This also has the desired result:

```
echo filename.txt | sed 's/\..*//'     filename
```